# html after <textarea></textarea> appearing in textarea when run in browser. Only happens on Firefox

Tags: html, css

The following problem only happens in Firefox. The html after my textarea appears in the text box when the page runs in the browser. It works fine on Chrome and Safari. I've cleared my cache but it's still doing it. I can't work out why any code would appear in the box after the closing tag. Screenshot below to better explain the problem.[image][image][image]

```css
button {
 width: 176px;
 height: 47px;
 background: #6442ff;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: "Roboto";
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 18px;
 align-items: center;
 border: none;
}


.home-name {
 position: absolute;
 width: 828px;
 height: 38px;
 left: 303px;
 top: 4184px;

 background: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: Roboto;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 25px;

 /* identical to box height, or 167% */
 text-align: left;

 color: #eaeaea;
}

input[type=text] {
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-top: 2px;
}

.home-email {
 position: absolute;
 width: 406px;
 height: 38px;
 left: 303px;
 top: 4236px;

 background: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: Roboto;
 font-style: normal;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 18px;

 /* identical to box height */

 color: #d3d3d3;
}

.home-phone {
 position: absolute;
 width: 406px;
 height: 38px;
 left: 725px;
 top: 4236px;

 background: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: Roboto;
 font-style: normal;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 18px;

 /* identical to box height */

 color: #d3d3d3;
}

.home-message {
 position: absolute;
 width: 828px;
 height: 167px;
 left: 303px;
 top: 4288px;

 background: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: Roboto;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 18px;
 ;

 /* identical to box height */

 color: #eaeaea;
}

.home-message-contact {
 position: absolute;
 width: 163px;
 height: 47px;
 left: 638px;
 top: 4490px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
<title>Hello</title>
<body>
 <form>
        <div class="name-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="home-name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="phone-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="home-phone" required>
        </div>
        <div class="email-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="home-email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="message-form">
            <textarea placeholder="Message" class="home-message" required></textarea>
        </div>
        </form>
        <button class="home-message-contact" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: It works when when done through "Run code snippet" - However when I open the index.html file on my desktop I get the problem in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking on your code, you forgot to close `</head>`. Although it could be unclosed quote, or some script. Your code works fine. You can attach a full code of your file.

**UPDATED**

I'v recreated your issue. You forgot to close `</textarea>`

Like this

```
<textarea placeholder="Message" class="home-message" required></textarea>
```

This what happens when I removed `</textarea>`
[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Try to put `<button class="home-message-contact" type="submit">Submit</button>` inside  tag `<form>`.

Or use construction like this

```
<div>
  <form id="my-form">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name"></input>
  </form>

  <!-- ... -->

  <button type="submit" form="my-form">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I've just changed the screenshot to show inspector where you can see the <textarea> and </textarea>

Comment: Yes, there is a code in Inspector. I can see it although in my inspector. FF closed it automatically, but incorrect. Look through your code, not FF inspector.

Comment: click Ctrl + U in Firefox and post code please, not from inspector.

Comment: Just added two more screenshots to show </textarea>. One from Ctrl + U in Firefox and a screenshot from Visual code.

Comment: Can you post your code somewhere? the accurate code you are using. Full html page.

Comment: I guess this is the time to learn Github. Bear with me while I setup Github.

Comment: I've uploaded everything Github - https://github.com/FlashBangKev/Voltcube

Comment: Very strange, but it works perfectly. Do you see your issue here? https://test.focus.style/so/index.html

Comment: No. It works fine on the link that you provided. If I run index.html locally then I get the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212972/discussion-between-focus-style-and-flashbangkev).

Comment: Why does Name and Email no your screen have red shadows and where does 'dscdcsdsc ' text came from?

Comment: The red shadows are from clicking on the input fields and not entering any info. "dscdcsdsc" cam from me just typing in the box to make sure I could input data.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, however I found same results across browsers.
Closing of head is missing  `</head>` is your html

just change it and refresh on Firefox pressing Shift + F5.

Comment: Try to remove </textarea> and see what happens in FF